# C# string to Inno Setup

Tags: c#, interop, marshalling, inno-setup

I have a C# DLL in which exposes a method which generates a string.
I want to call this Method from Inno Setup and receive the string then.

```pascal
function GetInformationEx():String;
external 'GetInformationEx@{src}\data\tools\ZipLib.dll stdcall loadwithalteredsearchpath';

procedure ShowProgress(progress:Integer);
var 
    information : String;
begin
    WriteDebugString('ShowProgress called');
    if(progress > pbStateZip.position) then 
    begin
        pbStateZip.position := progress;
        lblState2.Caption  := IntToStr(progress)+' %';
        try
            information := GetInformationEx();
        except
            ShowExceptionMessage;
        end;
        //Do something with the information
    end
    if(progress >= 100)then 
    begin
        KillTimer(0,m_timer_ID);
        //Inform that the extraction is done
    end
    WriteDebugString('ShowProgress leave');
end;
```

Here is my simple C# part

```
[DllExport("GetInformationEx", CallingConvention = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static String GetInformationEx()
{
    return "Some simple text message || or heavy information"; 
}
```

My question is:
What kind of type do I have to send back to Inno Setup so that Inno Setup can handle it correctly?

Until now I get this message

[image]

PS: I read this post:
[Returning a string from a C# DLL with Unmanaged Exports to Inno Setup script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20776847/returning-a-string-from-a-c-sharp-dll-with-unmanaged-exports-to-inno-setup-scrip)
But I want the C# code to be in charge of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .NET `String` type definitely won't marshal to Pascal `string` type. The .NET does not know anything about Pascal types.

The .NET can marshal strings to character arrays (and Pascal can marshal string from character arrays). But when the string is a return type of a function, there's problem with allocation of the memory for the string (who allocates the memory, who releases it).

That's why [the solution in question you pointed to](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20776847/850848#20777930) suggests you to use by ref/out parameter, because this way the caller can provide a buffer the .NET can marshal the string to. So there are no problems with allocation.