# Inno Setup "could not call proc" from external dll

Tags: inno-setup

I'm trying to call a method from a dll file (C#) but I just get the "could not call proc" error message.
Here's my code:

ddl file:

```
public class InnoEncryption
{
    [DllExport("EncryptText", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static string EncryptText([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string text)
    {
        return SecretKeyEncryption.EncryptText(text);
    }
}
```

Inno.iss

```
[Files]
Source: "dll\InnoEncryption.dll"; Flags: dontcopy
Source: "dll\RGiesecke.DllExport.dll"; Flags: dontcopy

[Code]
function EncryptText(text: String): String;
external 'EncryptText@files:InnoEncryption.dll,RGiesecke.DllExport.dll stdcall loadwithalteredsearchpath delayload';

procedure MyProc();
var encryptedText: String;
begin
encryptedText := EncryptText(PasswordEdit.Text);
end
```

Comment: As mentioned in the answer to the duplicate question, you cannot "return" string from a function implemented in DLL. And it's twice as impossible, if the function is implemented in .NET/C#. That cannot work.

Comment: Actually this is even closer duplicate: [Returning a string from a C# DLL with Unmanaged Exports to Inno Setup script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20776847/850848).

Comment: Great job, thanks!