# Inno Setup - External .NET DLL with dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, dll, inno-setup, pascalscript

I am trying to use a custom DLL in a Inno Setup script during installation. I wrote a very simple function that basically checks a connection string for a MySQL database using MySQL .NET connector (there is no MySQL client on the target server). The code of this exported function is:

```csharp
public class DbChecker
{
    [DllExport("CheckConnexion", CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static int CheckConnexion([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string connexionString)
    {
        int success;
        try
        {
            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connexionString);
            connection.Open();
            connection.Close();
            success = 0;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            success = 1;
        }
        return success;
    }
}
```

The function is imported this way in Inno Setup :

```
[Files]
Source: "..\..\MyDll\bin\x86\Release\*"; Flags: dontcopy;
```

and

```pascal
[Code]
function CheckConnexion(connexionString: AnsiString): Integer;
external 'CheckConnexion@files:MyDll.dll,MySql.Data.dll stdcall setuponly loadwithalteredsearchpath';`
```

The problem is that the setup throws an exception at runtime:

> Runtime Error (at 53:207):
>
> External exception E0434352.

I think I have to use the `files` prefix because the function is called in the `NextButtonClick` event handler, before files are copied to the `{app}` directory.

Both `MyDll.dll` and `MySql.Data.dll` are correctly extracted to the `{tmp}` directory at runtime.

I tried both with and without the `loadwithalteredsearchpath` flag with the same result.

What I found is that this error code is a generic .NET runtime error code.

If I remove the part using `MySql.Data` it works perfectly fine (except that it does nothing...)

As advised on other threads I've been trying to log the error in my .NET code using `EventLog` and `UnhandledException` but I have the same exception no matter what (and no log source is created), even without the MySQL part. I checked EventLog permissions on my computer.

It seems that the exception is thrown as soon as I use anything else that "basic" C# code (whenever I try to load another DLL).

Comment: It is the Achilles heel of [DllExport].  Using try/catch is not enough, such code is also very likely to fail with very basic issues detected by the jitter.  FileNotFoundException for example.  Which much run *before* the code executes to try/catch cannot help.  Consider using the debugger to get ahead, select your installer in the Project > Properties > Debug window.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is probably a better way, but this will do.

Implement an initialization function (`Init` here) that sets up [`AppDomain.AssemblyResolve`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve) handler that looks for an assembly in the path of the main (executing) assembly:

```csharp
[DllExport("Init", CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static void Init()
{
    AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
    currentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(MyResolveEventHandler);
}

private static Assembly MyResolveEventHandler(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    string location = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
    AssemblyName name = new AssemblyName(args.Name);
    string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(location), name.Name + ".dll");
    if (File.Exists(path))
    {
        return Assembly.LoadFrom(path);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Import it to the Inno Setup:

```pascal
procedure Init(); external 'Init@files:MyDll.dll stdcall setuponly';
```

And call it before calling the function that needs the dependency (`CheckConnexion`).

---

Another solution might be this:
[Embedding DLLs in a compiled executable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/189549/850848)

---

Btw, no need for the `loadwithalteredsearchpath` flag. It has no effect on .NET assemblies imo. They are needed for native DLL dependencies: [Loading DLL with dependencies in Inno Setup fails in uninstaller with "Cannot import DLL", but works in the installer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65018560/850848).

Answer (score 2):

I found something else that might be helpful for anyone stumbling upon this page.

In my scenario, I have several C# methods that I call from InnoSetup using DllExport.  In one of those methods, I call another of the methods.  This caused Inno to throw "External exception E0434352".

If I moved the code to a method not called by InnoSetup, everything worked fine.

So...

```
[DllExport("Fu", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static int Fu()
{
    // Stuff
}

[DllExport("Bar", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static int Bar()
{
    Fu();
}
```

...causes InnoSetup to cry, but:

```
[DllExport("Fu", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static int Fu()
{
    LocalFu();  
}

private static int LocalFu()
{
    // Stuff
}

[DllExport("Bar", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static int Bar()
{
    // Stuff
    LocalFu();
    // Other stuff
}
```

...is fine.

I don't know if this is caused by Inno or DllExport, so I'll forgo direct derision and blame society as a whole for my lost morning.  (Or myself for being a new to this thing.)

Comment: Was pulling my hair out on this one... Thank you... Maybe the DllExport makes the method unavailable from .NET itself?

Answer (score 1):

I would like to expand upon Martin's answer. There is a way to resolve the assemblies without having to call an Init method first and that is by including a static constructor in your .NET class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    static MyClass()
    {
        AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
        currentDomain.AssemblyResolve += MyResolveEventHandler;
    }

    private static Assembly MyResolveEventHandler(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        var location = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
        var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(args.Name);
        var path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(location), assemblyName.Name + ".dll");
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            return Assembly.LoadFrom(path);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```