# Using Office Interop Application Object to get the PowerPoint version during installation with Inno Setup

Tags: vb.net, powerpoint, inno-setup, office-interop

During the installation of our PowerPoint add-in using Inno Setup installer, I need to get the currently used version of PowerPoint by querying an `Application.PowerPoint` object itself – instead of relying on registry entries [which can't be guaranteed to give the correct value](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/272609/reliably-setting-keys-in-windows-registry-for-a-vba-addin).

I have successfully implemented this for an MSI installer written with WIX [based on this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/272629/206380) using this code:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint

Public Class Environment

  Public Shared Function GetPowerPointVersion() As String

    Dim CurVer As String
    Dim thisPowerPoint As Object

    thisPowerPoint = New Application()
    CurVer = thisPowerPoint.Version
    thisPowerPoint.Quit()

    Return CurVer

  End Function

End Class
```

*I don't entirely trust this to work in all situations (maybe paranoid), so will put in try/catch blocks and use the registry method if this fails.*

I haven't been able to work out how to do a similar thing with Inno Setup installer. There are some examples of using DLLs – https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptdll – but I can't see how I could create a function callable from Inno Setup from this which would return the version number.

Comment: Would this help? [How can I call a .NET DLL from an Inno Setup script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45510/850848)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`CreateOleObject`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createoleobject) to call PowerPoint and return the version:

```pascal
[Code]
function GetPowerPointVersion(): string;
var
  MyPowerPoint: Variant;
begin
  MyPowerPoint := CreateOleObject('PowerPoint.Application');
  Result := MyPowerPoint.Version;
  MyPowerPoint.Quit;
end;
```

Comment: You should probably catch exceptions in this code (in case the object fails to create).

Comment: CreateOleObject will throw an exception, if not succesful. So, yes, the code should be placed in a try ... except or try ... finally section.

Comment: For those reading, the answer by the OP includes the exception handling.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, this is the Pascal Script code which I am now using to get the PowerPoint version – based on Matej's answer, with a fallback to checking the registry if that fails:

```pascal
function PowerPointVersion(): String;
var
  key: String;
  versionToUse: String;
  installedPowerPoint: Variant;
begin

  versionToUse := '';

  try
    installedPowerPoint := CreateOleObject('PowerPoint.Application');
    versionToUse := installedPowerPoint.Version;
    installedPowerPoint.Quit;
  except
    versionToUse := '';
  end;

  if versionToUse = '' then
  begin
    if RegQueryStringValue(GetHKLM, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\ClickToRun\Configuration','VersionToReport', key) then
    begin
      versionToUse := key;
      Delete(versionToUse, Pos('.', key), Length(key));
      versionToUse := versionToUse + '.0';
    end;
  end;

  if versionToUse = '' then
  begin
    if RegQueryStringValue(HKCR, 'PowerPoint.Application\CurVer\','', key) then
    begin
      StringChangeEx(key, 'PowerPoint.Application.', '', True);
      versionToUse := key;
      versionToUse := versionToUse + '.0';
    end;
  end;

  try
    // Check to see if versionToUse string can convert to a float: 
    StrToFloat(versionToUse);
    Result := versionToUse;
  except
    Result := '';
  end;

end;
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint` which is a NuGet package is not a good idea as it is not supported and will be prone to failure. [See this discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/76833).

This external C# code will work and can be set up to be called from Inno Setup. However, using `CreateOleObject` within Inno Setup Pascal code as described in the accepted answer is far simpler.

```
[SupportedOSPlatform("windows")]
public class PowerPointEnvironment
{
    public static string GetPowerPointVersion()
    {
        string CurVer = "";
        Type? PowerPointType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("PowerPoint.Application");
        if (PowerPointType != null)
        {
            dynamic? thisPowerPoint = Activator.CreateInstance(PowerPointType);
            if (thisPowerPoint != null)
            {
                CurVer = thisPowerPoint.version();
            }
        }
        return CurVer;
    }
}
```

Comment: Using the version number that the PowerPoint application returns may not give you all the information you need; every version from 2016 onward identifies as 16.0 (including the Office 365 versions). If you're checking in order to verify that a particular feature is supported, the version number may not help.

Comment: I am using the version number in order to find the right place in the registry to register an add-in. So, hopefully for that usage, the version number that the PowerPoint application returns will continue to be the right one for this purpose?

Comment: Yes, that'll work as you wish.  It's mainly using the version number to intuit which features are/aren't supported that's likely to be a problem.  You're good to go.